# Sequence switch in python

Tags: python

I am solving a problem in Python.

The general idea is that given a sequence of numbers, then pick out the numbers form this sequence according to a rule, then this pick-out numbers form a new list.

step1, Pick out the numbers in `odd` position (the position count from zero) and append to a new list.

step2, The remaining numbers form a new sequence.

step3, In the next round, pick out the numbers in `even` position of the new sequence, and append to a new list.

step4,  After this round, the remaining numbers forms a a new sequences.

Repeat this procedure until all the number in the original sequence have been pick out to for a new list.

For example, given a sequence [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8],

step1, Pick out the numbers in `odd` position, New_list = [1, 3, 5, 7]

step2, the remaining numbers form a new sequence is [0, 2, 4, 6, 8]

step3, pick out the numbers in `even` position of the new sequence, then the numbers [0, 4, 8] are picked out from the new sequence, and append to new list. then  New_list = [1, 3, 5, 7, 0, 4, 8]

step4, the remaining numbers form a new sequence is [2, 6]

Repeat step 1, then 6 is picked out append to  New_list = [1, 3, 5, 7, 0, 4, 8, 6] 
Repeat step 2, then 2 is picked out append to New_list = [1, 3, 5, 7, 0, 4, 8, 6, 2], then all numbers in original list are picked out. And the final result is the New_list.

I do not know how to implement it in Python. I got stuck in the first step, I want to use a `for` loop over the sequence and pick out the numbers according to odd or even index. But after picking out the numbers, the sequence changes. Then I have to start over a new `for` loop to loop over this new sequence, if the original sequence is very long. I will be too long and inefficient coding. Could someone gives me idea how to deal with this problem?

Comment: You can use slicing with a step to create new elements from all the even or odd elements, using `lst[::2]` and `lst[1::2]`. Alternate those in a `while` loop until there is nothing left.

Comment: @tobias_k Thank you. But the problem is the sequence I need to loop over is changing because each time the remaining numbers form a new sequence. So I can not loop over a fixed sequence `lst` . That is my problem.

Comment: That's exactly the point: You _don't_ loop over the sequence and pick/remove elements, you create a new sequence each time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use slices `[1::2]` and `[0::2]` to repeatedly get all the odd/even numbered elements of the list. Here, `[X:Y:Z]` meanst "start at X and go until Y in steps of Z", and if any of those are empty, like Y, the defaults are `[0:len:1]`. Just alternatively add the odd ones to the new list, and retain the even ones and vice versa until the list is empty. You can use a counter variable and modulo `%` to decide the start step for which iteration.

```
lst = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
new, i = [], 1
while lst:
    new += lst[i%2::2]
    lst = lst[1-i%2::2]
    i += 1
```

Afterwards, `new` is `[1, 3, 5, 7, 0, 4, 8, 6, 2]`.

Comment: Thank you so much !